# Host name not recognized error

Tags: haskell, deployment, yesod

I've been trying to setup keter for my yesod website, but I'm running into a bit of problems with the following:

```
Welcome to Keter

The hostname you have provided, 127.0.0.1:3000, is not recognized.
```

From what I gather, it's related to the `host` value in some settings file.

So, my question is, is it in the config file for keter, or is it app specific? (I'm using the yesod framework), and what exactly should it be set to?

## EDIT:

Thanks to snoyberg for pointing out that the ip was wrong (had completely overlooked it), it's been changed now.

#### To update the question a bit

I checked the error log files for the app, and it said:

```
HsCMS: user error (SQLite3 returned ErrorCan'tOpen while attempting to perform open "HsCMS_production.sqlite3".)
```

This would seem to have something to do with permissions. This happens when starting keter with sudo (even tried starting as root), but it doesn't happen if i go into /opt/keter/temp and do `./dist/build/HsCMS/HsCMS` from there. So, is this a bug with keter (which i doubt) or am i doing something wrong? Shouldn't sudo be enough to give permissions to keter?

## UPDATE/SOLUTION

Thanks to snoyberg for helping me narrow the problem to a permissions problem. The problem in my case was that I had, stupidly, set the `setuid` in the config to a user, and thus it didn't have permissions in the folder. I'm accepting snoybergs answer, because it was what lead to this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.01` is not a valid IP address. Perhaps you meant `127.0.0.1`?

The problem is that the *virtual hostname* is not recognized. Each Keter app must specify a virtual hostname which it listens on. This is given by the `host` property in the app itself. If you look at [the README example](https://github.com/snoyberg/keter#bundles), the hostname would be `www.yesodweb.com`.

Comment: Wow, did not notice that the IP was wrong, lol.. I found out that the ip part was because of my nginx config, so changed to `127.0.0.1`. I was checking the keter log file, and it seems that it keeps trying to restart the process. Could be it perhaps be that since the process never gets started, it displays this message?

Comment: Definitely the case. Each app gets its own log file (both for stdout and stderr), so you need to check to see what errors are being generated.

Comment: I checked the log file, and it said `HsCMS: user error (SQLite3 returned ErrorCan'tOpen while attempting to perform open "HsCMS_production.sqlite3".)` . Don't know why exactly, since I'm able to run the app normally, but this happens when using keter :/

Comment: It could be a file permission issue.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect these comments a bit. It would seem that it doesn't have permission using sudo (or as root), but starting the app in the temp folder manually works for some reason. I don't know if this has something to do with keter, or my setup?

Comment: It's not Keter that doesn't have permissions, it's your app. I've never had this experience before, but that doesn't prove anything. Can you see if this happens with an out-of-the-box Yesod scaffolding? And maybe now's a good time to move discussion to the mailing list.

Comment: I have just tried with an out-of-the-box Yesod scaffold and it produces the same SQLite3 error. Sure, we can move it there :) I'm assuming you're referring to the google group for Yesod? If yes, then I'll move it there ASAP! :)

Comment: Yes, I meant the Google Group.

Comment: Moved to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/yesodweb/f1jdzNVj4DU